# Dynamic DNS registration of a client by the DHCP. How is the record updated?

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, windows-server-2012

With dynamic DNS where the clients are registered by the DHCP server, I cannot figure out, from where the DHCP server gets the clients name?
I mean the DHCP server just offer clients ip-numbers right?
Second I understand that the client becomes the owner of its record on the DNS and can change the record, but why on earth should it do that?
I mean in this case a record is just an A record, which gives the relation between
the clients name and ip number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean the DHCP server just offer clients ip-numbers right?

No. BOOTP was relatively simple, but DHCP leases can include many additional options – suggested DNS servers, NTP servers, domain name, and so on. Most clients will send a lease request containing the [Host Name option (12)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#section-3.14) with the computer's hostname filled in. Some clients also support the [FQDN option (81)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4702).

> I understand that the client becomes the owner of its record on the DNS and can change the record

No and yes. There are actually **two kinds** of dynamic DNS:

- In ISC-style dynamic DNS (managed through DHCP), this doesn't happen at all. Everything is done by the DHCP server whenever clients obtain address leases. The client doesn't have any access to its record.

  (Note: Do not mistake the DNS term ['owner name'](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7719#page-8) for actual ownership. This term simply refers to the name of the record itself (as opposed to various names that might be found *inside* that record).)
- In Windows-style (Active Directory) dynamic DNS, it's the opposite: computers themselves *always* directly add and update their own records in AD using RFC2136, and the DHCP server isn't involved at all.

  In dynamic AD domains, the clients indeed become owners of their own record – for the simple reason that they'll have to update it themselves whenever their IP address changes. (Again, the DHCP server doesn't manage Active Directory DNS.)
- Of course, these two styles *can* be mixed, supporting both DHCP-managed and self-managed updates. If you provide DHCP from an AD-joined Windows server, it's possible that it supports updating the Active Directory domain from DHCP leases, and automatically gives record ownership just in case the client will want to switch to self-updating later on.

*(Yes, I'm aware that RFC 2136 was written by ISC. But ISC dhclient rarely if ever uses it, while Microsoft Windows always does.)*

Comment: "they'll have to update it themselves whenever their IP address changes" I assume that the client on regular basis also has to tell the DNS that the IP-address is still valid? Is that TTL?

Comment: @user2304458: Yes, the client possibly needs to do so – but it's **not** because of the regular DNS TTL. (That's only relevant to response caching, not to primary storage.) Instead, the DNS server might support a _second_, separate kind of timestamp that tells it how long to keep the record in storage. Windows DNS Server actually has this feature – you can see a field labelled "Record time stamp". So if a computer doesn't update its own records for several days, the Windows DNS server's "scavenging" function will delete them. But this feature is nonstandard.